# How does the input voltage affect the current consumption of a microcontroller?

Tags: microcontroller, current-measurement, low-power, microprocessor

Is there a relationship between the current used by a microcontroller unit (MCU) and its input voltage?

In other words, given a MCU with a wide-input range (e.g. 2.7 to 5.5V for the ATmega328P), will it use the same amount of current for a given operation undepending on the input voltage?

I'm not sure if there is a generic answer to the question as it might depend on the particular MCU. I'm asking this question because low-power figures (e.g. in datasheets) seem to always be expressed as current (e.g. 1 μA for deep sleep mode) and never in Watt or similar.

Comment: More voltage = more leakage current =  more static power. Also more charge stored and discharged in each parasitic capacitor per switching operation so higher dynamic power for the same speed.

Comment: You'll find the clock frequency and the type of code it's running have a bigger effect than the supply voltage. And of course, the time spent in low power modes has the biggest effect.

Comment: Don't be too hasty to accept an answer. There are a lot of users from different time zones here, questions with marked answers usually attract less attention thus reducing the chance to get an excellent answer from a different person. I'd say wait at least a day and select your answer then (if you have gotten any).

Comment: Can we say that typically more voltage to the MCU = a bit more current but not less?

Answer (score 2):

This really depends on the implementation of the microcontroller and cannot be answered in a general way.

Some parts will always be affected by the supply voltage, for example the dynamic power consumption of GPIO when they are switching.

Some microcontrollers have internal voltage regulators for the core or other parts of it so they will internally run on the same voltage all the time, rendering the effect of the external supply voltage minimal.

Others don't have this and their power consumption will depend on the supply voltage. But still they usually only give figures for current and not power.

That is because the tables are for specific use cases which are usually either written on top of the table or below the table. In most cases it will contain something of "Ta = 25 °C, VDD = 3 V unless otherwise noted".

For example a note from the STM32G0 datasheet:
[image: example of a datasheet note]

Some manufacturers will provide detailed plots or tables for different scenarios but as the combinations are incredibly complex, you usually only get one thing and have to measure all the rest yourself if you really need it.

Answer (score 1):

Please read the datasheet very carefully.

[image]

There are different values for power supply current at different VCC voltages of 3 and 5 V.

Comment: You might want to find a better example picture because this one shows different clock rates for the different voltages which confuses things (the clock rate also affects current consumption).  Finding one that shows the same clock rate at different voltages would improve this answer.

Comment: I picked the ATmega as an example because it was common. I did not read its datasheet in particular. However, this is not a direct comparison as different frequencies are used (also 16MHz is not supported at 3V).

Answer (score 0):

long channel mosfets have a square_law effect of vdd upon Idd.

Short channel mosfets behave differently.